# Menu flowing out of div when reducing browser's window or zoom with it

Tags: html, css

This is complete code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                overflow-x: hidden; 
                text-align: center;
            }
            div#box {               
                background-color: green;
                border-radius: 1em;        
                opacity: 0.6;
                margin: 0em 2.5em 0em 2.5em;
                padding: 1em;   
            }
            li {
                display: inline;
                margin: 0em;
                padding: 0em;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0em;
                padding: 0em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>                       
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I reduce the size of the browser's window or I zoom it to maximum value the text is flowing out. 
How can I fix it by adapting the box to text so it's not flowing out?

Comment: I think nobody is going to zoom in your website page to the maximum value

Comment: of course, but it is just for give a example of the problem.  Is possible solve it?

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW Not handling something that is possible for the user to do just because "nobody is going to do that" is a VERY BAD practice! 
I think the question of Marcello is legitimate.

Comment: Remove `white-space: nowrap;` to start

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone did happen to zoom your page to 500% lol, this should solve it: 
You can set your `<ul>` to `position: relative`, and your `#box` to `position: absolute`, and the text should never flow outside of the border of its parent. However, this would make the #box background/element cease at the edge of its content, so to make the green background span a wider width like you seem to want, you just have to set a certain width or use padding-top etc values.

Removing `whitespace: nowrap` works, but not when reducing browser window to half and zooming fully (it still overflows the bounds of the `div`).